# Issue Importing .xlsx into Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to export a .xlsx file in to oracle via the import wizard. However, when I select the .xlsx file nothing happens, usually when I import .csv I then specify format etc, but I am just brought back to the home screen. The file is quite small so I don't see why this wouln't work. Does anyone have any advice?
[image]

Comment: please share your Excel file, or we can't really do anything to help. otherwise i can guess...like maybe a macro or some calculated field is messing things up? d

Comment: Hi thatjeffsmith, this is what is happening. In the .xlsx file I have a column which contains range values e.g '0 - 5', '6 - 10' etc.. When I save this .xlsx as a .csv ranges that look like dates convert to a date format e.g. 6 - 10 converts to 06 - Oct (which has a very different numerical value). There are no macro's running, and it appears to be the default set up in .csv files. So I basically would prefer if the range did not convert to the date format when I save as .csv.

Comment: so you got multiple things going, getting the data to import is step 1, save the excel to a new file, SANS any macros, and try again

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to convert your excel data into csv and import it as usual. Depending on the size of file, version of sql developer, operating system there seems to be some problems with memory (especialy on 64-bit systems with 64-bit jdk) though the file looks small.
Some report says they are succeded to import xls file after increasing the SQL Developer virtual memory limit by adding a line like AddVMOption -Xmx1280M or larger into SQLDeveloper.conf file.
Converting xls to csv is easy, fast an less stressful than messing with config file.

Comment: I should have highlighted that, I don't want to use a csv file as it is converting certain cells to date format where I just want them to be numeric. Its a strange nuance that is causing problems! Appreciate your points though.